# Unable to insert a break point in CUDA (.cu) file

Tags: debugging, cuda, nsight

When I try to insert a break point in my .cu file, I get a message "BreakPoint cannot be inserted at this point"

I have installed Parallel NSight.

Is there any setting I need to change or am I missing something ?

Comment: I assume you are trying to set a breakpoint in device code, not host code.  Let's say your kernel name is foo.  Then tell the debugger to run until foo (i.e. set a breakpoint at the entry to your kernel foo).  Then let the code run till that point.  After that, the kernel context is loaded and you should be able to set a breakpoint at other places within that kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're using a Debug build, not Release.